# Display Text in Thumb

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml

I'm trying to show a text in the `Thumb` of a `Slider`.
I implemented a `Converter` that converts the `Value` to a string which is set as the  `DataContext` of the `Thumb`.

Unfortunately that just results in the Thumb looking Disabled without any text at all.

Is there any other way aside from replacing the Thumb by a TextBox?

Changed code for the custom Slider:

```
<Thumb x:Name="VerticalThumb" AutomationProperties.AccessibilityView="Raw" Background="{ThemeResource SliderThumbBackgroundThemeBrush}" Grid.Column="1" DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=Value, Converter={StaticResource SecondsToTime}}" Height="{ThemeResource SliderTrackThemeHeight}" Grid.Row="1" Style="{StaticResource SliderThumbStyle}" Width="{ThemeResource SliderTrackThemeHeight}"/>
```

SecondsToTime (: IValueConverter)

```
class SecondsToTime : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        int seconds = (int)(double)value;
        return (seconds > 3600 ? (seconds / 3600) + ":" : "") + ((seconds % 3600) < 600 ? "0" : "") + ((seconds % 3600) / 60) + ":" + ((seconds % 60) < 10 ? "0" : "") + (seconds % 60);
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        string[] times = (value as string).Split(':');
        int pow = 0;
        return times.Aggregate(0, (seed, part) => { return seed + (int)Math.Pow(Int16.Parse(part), pow++); });
    }
}
```

Comment: It's possible to set text to a thumb, however the API can be tricky to navigate. Can you provide sample code ?

Comment: Sure, there you go, but I doubt that there's anything useful.
It's just what I wrote already. Didn't change anything else in the Slider Template yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The API to set the thumb text is called the tooltip service. [ToolTipService class on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.tooltipservice.aspx)

```
<Thumb>
    <ToolTipService.ToolTip>
        <TextBlock Text="Your text"/>
    </ToolTipService.ToolTip>
</Thumb>
```

Comment: Ty works like a charm.
One thing: If one sets the `ToolTipService.ToolTip` attached property in the `Thumb` to the `Binding` that is to be displayed it won't work.
It will just have the value of the time when you hold the slider and the tooltip won't disappear nor move.
Your `TextBlock` version works nonetheless.
Kinda weird since that should be the same thing afaik.

Any idea why my `Thumb` is now looking disabled (grey border and background) even if the style is not applied?

Comment: From your description it seems like that's the default look for TextBlock.RequestedTheme="Light"

Comment: Wasn't TextBlock. TextBlock doesn't have a `Background` nor a `Border`. It was the `Default Theme` for `ToolTip`.
Should've known that but I remembered it having a white border.
Ty for your help.